# java.lang.internalerror while calling a webservice using Jersey api

Tags: jaxb, jersey-client

I have an application that has two module the client and server which talk with each other using jersey api. Each business object will have an interface which will be used by the client and server module to create the classes. 
here is the structure of the two modules:

```
Client:
  |- IBusinessObjectSupper.java 
  |- IBusinessObject1.java 
  |- IBusinessObject2.java 
  |- IBusinessObject3.java
  |- IAssociation.java 
  |- CBusinessObjectSupper.java 
  |- CBusinessObject1.java 
  |- CBusinessObject2.java 
  |- CBusinessObject3.java
  |- CAssociation.java 
  |- CWebServiceManager.java 

Server:
  |- IBusinessObjectSupper.java 
  |- IBusinessObject1.java 
  |- IBusinessObject2.java 
  |- IBusinessObject3.java
  |- IAssociation.java 
  |- CBusinessObjectSupper.java 
  |- CBusinessObject1.java 
  |- CBusinessObject2.java 
  |- CBusinessObject3.java
  |- CAssociation.java 
  |- CWebServiceResource.java
```

The `I**.java` are the interfaces and `C**.java` are classes that implements the respective interfaces. Also `CBusinessObject1`, `CBusinessObject2` and `CBusinessObject3` extends the `CBusinessObjectSuper` class.

The following is snipper code of `CBusinessObjectSuper.java` and `CAssociations` on for both module

```
class CBusinessObjectSuper{
  private String id;
@xmlelement(type="CAssociations.class")
  private List<IAssociations> associations;
//setter and getter;
}
@XmlSeeAlso({CBusinessObject1.class,CBusinessObject2.class,CBusinessObject3.class})
class CAssociations{
   list<IBusinessObjectSupper> businessObjectList;   
};
```

The `CWebServiceManager` create a `WebResource` and calls the webservice. 
the `CWebServiceResource` class has a method which is defined as a webservice url which will create the `CBusinessObject` and returns back the object to `WebService Manager`.

When I am calling the webResource using following statement:

```
webResource.post();
```

I am getting the below exception

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.InternalError` at `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:128)`

Iam providing the full stacktrace to this quesion at the end.

Please let me konw what could be the issue. and I cannot attach original codebase.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:42)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:67)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(AbstractList.java:339)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(ClassInfoImpl.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:134)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getBaseClass(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:40)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:244)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:304)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:319)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:430)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:191)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:184)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:554)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:674)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.post(WebResource.java:241)
at com.apple.ist.gcrm.domain.company.client.CompanyManager.get(CompanyManager.java:77)
at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```